# R counting strings variables in each row of a dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this, where each row represents a samples, and has repeats of the the same strings

```
> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  a  a  d  d  b
2  c  a  b  d  a
3  d  b  a  a  b
4  d  d  a  b  c
5  c  a  d  c  c
```

I want to be able to create a new dataframe, where ideally the headers would be the string variables in the previous dataframe (a, b, c, d) and the contents of each row would be the number of occurrences of each the respective variable from 
the original dataframe. Using the example from above, this would look like

```
> df2
   a  b  c  d 
1  2  1  0  2  
2  2  1  1  1  
3  2  1  0  1
4  1  1  1  2  
5  1  0  3  1
```

In my actual dataset, there are hundreds of variables, and thousands of samples, so it'd be ideal if I could automatically pull out the names from the original dataframe, and alphabetize them into the headers for the new dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

You may try

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df)))
```

Or

```
mtabulate(split(as.matrix(df), row(df)))
```

Or using `base R`

```
Un1 <- sort(unique(unlist(df)))
t(apply(df ,1, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=Un1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `stack` the columns and then use `table`:

```
table(cbind(id = 1:nrow(mydf), 
            stack(lapply(mydf, as.character)))[c("id", "values")])
#    values
# id  a b c d
#   1 2 1 0 2
#   2 2 1 1 1
#   3 2 2 0 1
#   4 1 1 1 2
#   5 1 0 3 1
```